# NSPredicate Maximum time with swift2

Tags: ios, swift, expression, swift2, nspredicate

I am using coredata and I  want to find maximum time in coredata.
How do I write?

```
  let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "contentDate = '？？？' ", "")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wain said, to find maximum value you rather have to define `SortDescriptor` then `Predicate`:

```
let sortByTimeDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortByTimeDescriptor]
```

You are interested just in the one (maximum) value so it's also good practice to set fetch limit for performance reason:

`fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1`

Then just execute request and get first object from results array:

```
let results = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
let maxTimeEntity = results.first
```

Notice that `executeFetchRequest` can throw and error and you have to handle it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

To find a maximum it makes more sense to sort and ask for the first item than to try to create a predicate.

You can also look at an expression using @max to get the value back on its own if the container object isn't important.